# change listview background colour on button press

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, highlight

I know how to set colours on the listview, using bindView. So when ever it is created, (or scrolled onto screen) the colour is set...

But how do I go through existing views, without destroying and re-creating the entire thing.

Aka, If i press a button, I wish to highlight all existing on screen items (in the listview) that have second field in the cursor = `False`

```
Item 1, True
Item 2, True
Item 3, False -- Should highlight Green on button press.
Item 4, True
```

Edit:

Currently I do this, but it requires refreshing the cursor.

```
    int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition(); // Obtain where list is
    lv.setAdapter(null);


    Cursor cursor = SqlDB.getCursor();
    adap = new MyAdaptor(this, R.layout.list, cursor, columns, to, true, 0);

    lv.setAdapter(adap);
    lv.setSelection(currentPosition); // Move back to where it was
```

Comment: are you using a custom adapter ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma Yes, it extends `SimpleCursorAdapter` but is just a custom layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the onClick event of the button you need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() which will refresh the data in the listview and in turn will set your preferred color to the items that have the second field in the cursor == false

Comment: Thanks. If you see my question, you can see what i was doing. I have now removed both `SetAdapter` and replaced, reacquiring the cursor, with your suggestion. It occured to me from your answer. I could have just called `setAdapter` using my global `adap`, and not had to go to the DB anyway. I am going to remove the position parts, to see if its needed.

Comment: And to quickly follow up.. I dont need to set the position, as nothing is changed. That method you mention is fantastic! :) I knew it existed, and ive used it before, but i never realised it could do that.